# PHP - in_array isn't finding my value

Tags: php, pdo

I'm a newb and I got a problem with in_array...

So this is my array $allUsers (received by a SQL-Query for Usernames)

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => admin
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => kingChräbi
        )
```

Now If a new member wants to register, I want to check in this array if it's already existent:

```
if(!in_array($username,$allUsers)){....
```

eventhough it is to when $username is NOT in $allUsers do .... it's just skipping to else also if the user is existing :(

$username is set before with

```
$username = $_POST['name'];
```

and working as it should (i can echo it without a problem, is exactly test or test2 without whitespace or anything)

I really looked around alot, but I can't find anything like my problem here... Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: `in_array()` requires a **value** and **a single-dimensional array**. You're currently passing a 2 d array. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: alright, So I should write a function returning true / false with a foreach in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although question itself is quite silly, as you have to realize what array you are working with, the quick solution, based on PDO tag, would be as follows: instead of `fetchAll()` use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)`

Or, rather you need to learn SQL as well, and find users not by means of selecting them ALL from database which makes no sense, but by asking a database to find a user for you

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=?");
$stm->execute(array($_POST['name']));
$user = $stm->fetch();

if ($user) { // <---HERE YOU GO
```

Comment: Hope you got that you have to use second option only.

Answer (score 0):

The `in_array()` does not work with multi-dimensional arrays.  You better flatten your array and then do a search for the keyword.

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr)); //<-- Pass your array here
$new_arr = array();
foreach($it as $v) {
    $new_arr[]=$v;
}
if(in_array('test',$new_arr))
{
    echo "Exists !";
}
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/125883)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching a 2-D array for a value under the key of `"name"`.
Using `array_map()` or simple `foreach` loop should work -

```
$username = "admin";
$key = "name";
if(!in_array($username,array_map(function($v)use($key){return $v[$key];},$allUsers))){
    echo "No found";
}else{
    echo "Found";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using:

While ($ row=mysql_fetch_assoc ($ result) {

$ data [] = $ row
}

Remove the [] to not create a multidimensional array.